# How to get SVG elements by coordinates?

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to get the SVG elements for some given coordinates.

I tried to use `document.elementsFromPoint(x,y)`. However, it only returns the main `svg` element itself, not the sub elements (circles, paths etc) inside svg.

=>How can I find the SVG elements for given coordinates?

Example html file where I want to move a red circle on a green path by pressing arrow keys. Movement should only be allowed if the circle stays on on the green path.

*Screenshot:*

[image]

*Demo:*

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function onClick() {
      alert('You have clicked the circle.')
    }

    function onKeyPress(event) {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
          moveLeft();
          break;
        case 38:
          moveUp();
          break;
        case 39:
          moveRight();
          break;
        case 40:
          moveDown();
          break;
        default:
      }

    }

    function moveDown() {
      console.log('down');
      var path = d3.select('#path');

      var robot = d3.select('#robot');
      var cx = Number(robot.attr('cx'));
      var cy = Number(robot.attr('cy'));

      var newcy = cy + 10;
      var elements = document.elementsFromPoint(cx, newcy)
      if (path in elements) {
        robot.attr('cy', cy + 10);
      }

    }

    function moveUp() {
      console.log('up');
      var robot = d3.select('#robot');
      var cy = Number(robot.attr('cy'));
      robot.attr('cy', cy - 10);
    }

    function moveLeft() {
      console.log('left')
      var robot = d3.select('#robot');
      var cx = Number(robot.attr('cx'));
      robot.attr('cx', cx - 10);
    }

    function moveRight() {
      console.log('right');
      var robot = d3.select('#robot');
      var cx = Number(robot.attr('cx'));
      robot.attr('cx', cx + 10);
    }

    function onLoad() {
      console.log('onload')
      this.addEventListener('keydown', event => onKeyPress(event));
    }
  </script>

  <svg width='500px' height='500px' focusable onload="onLoad()">
            <text x='0' y='20' fill='blue'>Hello world from within svg! Press arrow keys to move the  circle:</text>            
            <path id="path" d="M100 100 L 100 200 L 200 200" stroke='green' fill="transparent"/>
            <circle id="robot" cx="100" cy="100" r="5" fill='red' onclick="onClick()" />
        </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: document.elementsFromPoint also works for SVG elements, but it's relative to the viewport, while cx and cy are relative to the svg's viewBox. Here you need to add the body's padding. Also, `elements` will be an Array, you don't check if an Array contains an element by using `in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [Document.elementsFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint) is relative to the viewport you can use [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) that also is relative to the viewport. So, the robot position (the center) is the result of the x/y position plus half the width/height. And after finding the array of elements you can test if `indexOf()` is more than -1.

```css
svg {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>  

<body>
    <script>
        var step = 10;
        
        function onLoad(){
            console.log('onload')
            disableKeyboardScrolling();  
            this.addEventListener('keydown', event => onKeyPress(event));
        }

        function disableKeyboardScrolling(){
             window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                if(["ArrowUp","ArrowDown","ArrowLeft","ArrowRight"].indexOf(e.code) > -1) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }, false);
        }

        function onClick(){
            alert('You have clicked the circle.')
        }


        function onKeyPress(event){             
            switch(event.code){
                case "ArrowLeft": moveLeft();
                    break;
                case "ArrowUp": moveUp();
                    break;
                case "ArrowRight": moveRight();
                    break;
                case "ArrowDown": moveDown();
                    break;
                default:
            }
                
        }

        function moveDown(){
            console.log('down');                
                    
            var robot = document.getElementById('robot');
            var coordinates = getCenterCoordinates(robot);
            var newx = coordinates[0];
            var newy = coordinates[1] + step;   
            if (isOnAllowedPath(newx, newy)) {
                let cy = Number(robot.getAttribute('cy'))
                let newCy = cy + step;
                robot.setAttribute('cy', newCy);
            }
                        
        }           

        function moveUp(){
            console.log('up');

            var robot = document.getElementById('robot');
            var coordinates = getCenterCoordinates(robot);
            var newx = coordinates[0];
            var newy = coordinates[1] - step;   
            if (isOnAllowedPath(newx, newy)) {
                let cy = Number(robot.getAttribute('cy'))
                let newCy = cy-step;
                robot.setAttribute('cy', newCy);
            }           
        }

        function moveLeft(){
            console.log('left')  
                
            var robot = document.getElementById('robot');
            var coordinates = getCenterCoordinates(robot);
            var newx = coordinates[0] -step;
            var newy = coordinates[1];  
            if (isOnAllowedPath(newx, newy)) {
                let cx = Number(robot.getAttribute('cx'))
                let newCx = cx-step;
                robot.setAttribute('cx', newCx);
            }           
        }

        function moveRight(){
            console.log('right');

            var robot = document.getElementById('robot');
            var coordinates = getCenterCoordinates(robot);
            var newx = coordinates[0] +step;
            var newy = coordinates[1];  
            if (isOnAllowedPath(newx, newy)) {
                let cx = Number(robot.getAttribute('cx'))
                let newCx = cx+step;
                robot.setAttribute('cx', newCx);
            }                   
        }
        

        function getCenterCoordinates(robot){
            let rect = robot.getBoundingClientRect();
            let x = rect.x + rect.width / 2;
            let y = rect.y + rect.height / 2;
            return [x, y]
        }

        function isOnAllowedPath(x,y){
            var allowedPaths = document.getElementsByClassName('allowed-path'); 
            var elementsAtPosition = document.elementsFromPoint(x,y);
            for(allowedPath of allowedPaths){
                let isAllowed = elementsAtPosition.indexOf(allowedPath) > -1;
                if (isAllowed){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;                   
        }

    </script>

    <svg 
        width='500px' 
        height='500px'  
        focusable       
        onload="onLoad()"
    >
        <text x='0' y='20' fill='blue'>Hello world from within svg! Please move the circle with arrow keys:</text>          
        <path class="allowed-path" d="M100 100 L 100 200 L 200 200" stroke='green' fill="transparent"/>
        <path class="allowed-path" d="M200 200 L 200 100 L 300 100" stroke='blue' fill="transparent"/>
        <circle id="robot" cx="100" cy="100" r="5" fill='red' onclick="onClick()" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```